# Which topology belongs with which set? A question about weak convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am reading a statement of Goldstein's Theorem that reads (here $J$ is the embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$):

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $B$ the closed unit ball of
>   $X$, and $B^{**}$ the closed unit ball of $X^{**}$. Then the the weak-* closure of $J(B)$ is $B^{**}$.

A statement in the proof reads:

> We leave it as an exercise to show $B^{**}$ is weak-* closed.

I'm am confused by this statement, we assumed $B^{**}$ to be the closed unit ball in $X^{**}$. Doesn't this mean $B^{**}$ is closed with respect to the topology on $X^{**}$ (which $\textit{is}$ the weak-* topology)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say "the closed unit ball in $X^{**}$" without any specification of the topology, we usually mean the closure in the norm of $X^{**}$. In other words "the topology on $X^{**}$" is that inudced by the norm, not the weak-star topology.

Comment: okay what is the weak-* topology on $X^{**}$ then? the weak topology will be induced by functionals on $X^{**}$? then the weak-* topology given by pointwise evaluation of those functionals?

Comment: The weak-star topology is defined on a dual space. Since $X^{**}$ is the dual of $X^{*}$, the weak-star topology on $X^{**}$ is the one generated by elements of $X^*$ acting as linear functionals on $X^{**}$.  In other words, a (balanced) basic-neighborhood of zero in the weak-star topology on $X^{**}$ has the form:
$\{x^{**}\in X^{**}: |x_i^{*}(x^{**})|<\epsilon,\ \ 1\leq 1\leq n\}$ for some choice of $x_i^*\in X^*$. A sequence $x^{**}_j$ in $X^{**}$ converges to $x^{**}$ in the weak-star topology if and only if $x_j^{**}(x^*)\to x^{**}(x^*)$ for every $x^*\in X^*$.

Comment: My understanding was that the dual space provides linear functionals on the orginal space. If $X^{**}$ is dual to $X^*$ then shouldn't $x^{**}$ be a functional defined over  $x^* \in X^*$? Then the neighborhood at zero would look like  (see below)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mIP0W6f

Comment: Sorry the interpreter was thinking my ** was bolding

Comment: Oh sorry, you are defining the weak-* topology. Nvm -- ok I think I get it. I am still confused by this definition of weak-* base I think. Perhaps I'll go back to my book and formulate another question about it.